# Automatically Accept Answers to Old Questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21805734/loading-json-via-ajax-with-ngtable-parameters?rq=1) and was thinking to myself, self: "wow!" this question is a year old without an accepted answer. Obviously the answer that was provided and up voted 13 times is a good resolution to the question.

So my question or proposal is this:

Shouldn't after a year and over 10k views this question have an answer accepted? It is apparent the OP hasn't continued to participate. So why should the user who supplied a quality answer not receive closure?

At some point something could come along and clean these situations up. Though there may not be many of them. If this question is inappropriate or out of context feel free to down vote me straight into the abyss. There may be another question or resolution I am unaware of. Anyways, I just felt i would bring it up.

Comment: Would you move the checkmark if the asker accepted an answer a long time ago, and a newer answer has become more highly voted?  Being the only element of Q&A that can only be maintained by a single person, accepted answers are always a special case.  (In my opinion, they're a vestige from when SO was small enough that an individual's opinion was valuable, and are now more trouble than they're worth.)

Comment: No only for questions with a lack of participation on the OPs part

Comment: But the asker _has_ failed to participate by not updating the checkmark to reflect the best answer.

Comment: Which would be why stack overflow would step in and acknowledge what the community has found helpful. Since in time these are all community questions anyways. Obviously it was already asked. But it just dawned on me how many times someone asked a question many people found useful and then just stopped participating.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The checkmark only ever means anything to the OP.  All it really says is, "This answer helped the OP out with their question."

That does *not* make the answer the best, or in some cases, even correct.  There have been answers which are blatantly wrong or misinformed that have been accepted.

Automatically accepting those answers is not worth the trouble, since it would send conflicting signals.  We shouldn't presume that any one answer helped the OP more without them telling us first.

Comment: Its not just about helping the OP but every user who comes along afterwards.

Comment: @kcbeard:  I genuinely worry that, for a question with multiple answers, that there are users that *only* and *exclusively* read the accepted answer.  It's like saying there's only one way to do something in this industry, which in the vast majority of cases, is a flat-out lie.  I would say that a user should be prepared to read *more* than just the accepted answer if they're looking for an answer.  Who knows - the accepted answer may not answer their question entirely.

Comment: But at some point isn't it the communities question and no longer the OP's? hence after a year why the up votes become significant. The community has said by upvoting this is the resolution that helped me when i found this question. I guess it is just "a check mark". But it seems to me that the person who answered is getting short changed.

Comment: @kcbeard:  Short changed?  How?  The 15 rep they'd get from someone accepting it?  That only happens *once*.  Every upvote they get from someone *else* coming along and thinking that their answer is correct is 10 rep *every time*, save for the times one has hit the rep cap.  I don't see how this short changes the answerer.

Comment: @kcbeard The community's opinion is reflected by the votes.  That the checkmark carries any more weight than a single vote is arguably a misfeature.

Comment: @Makoto I am not saying they are short changed in rep by stack overflow. They are shortchanged by the OPs lack of desire to participate in the community.

Comment: @kcbeard:  You said it earlier:  after a point of time it's no longer about the OP.  If they don't want to participate after they've got an answer, that's their prerogative.  I can't even count the number of people that I've answered questions for who haven't come back, and in retrospect, it really doesn't matter all that much...

Comment: Would it be reasonable to notify the OP "consider accepting an answer for this question if it has helped you" ?