# Review queue to cleanup old unanswered questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions

Would it be feasible to add a review queue to see if any answer on very old, inactive questions should be selected *or if we can at least remove the question from the unanswered list*?

**The problem**

When I browse Android questions from a mobile device I can order them by unanswered. If I go straight to the end of the list they uniformly have 6 answers but nothing accepted. I imagine that's the result of people like me seeing if they can answer and close any old questions.

With the random sample I looked at, most of the asking users never returned even on the posts where they commented that an answer solved their problem; and with so many pages of questions in that state, questions in the middle of the list have 0 answers and get very little attention (while the ones at the end keep racking up views).

**My thoughts on a solution**

It occurred to me that it might be possible to create a review queue for questions which have a criteria something like

- Have answers
- Have no selected answer
- Are older than one year (?)
- OP has not been since for one year or more

Where review requires the reviewer to vote which (if any) post answers the question (with a none option when no answer is suitable). I would imagine it working something like the flagging system where the item could be removed from the queue if one answer has 5 or more agreeing votes and that answer has at least 50% more votes than the next most popular answer on that question (I really have no idea what it currently takes for an answer to be considered answered, without an accept check mark).

Once it reaches that point where it is considered answered the system could notify the OP to remind them to select their answer (and maybe to suggest the voted post) and would then remove the answer from the unanswered queue.

(The general consensus is that an accept mark means *this answer was helpful to the person who asked* rather than *this answer solves the problem*, this means marking an answer as accepted isn't an acceptible solution, although because of answer ordering, I don't agree with the 'checkmark only ever means anything to the OP' statement being completely true).

A review system like this would have the side benefit of exposing bad, old questions for close votes.

**What you should know before downvoting me and posting rage-inspired comments**

I know this questions will attract some negative responses, so to answer some specific thoughts that might have occurred to you:

- I have seen [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262672/can-moderators-make-an-answer-accepted-to-close-the-post) and its [two duplicates](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313384/automatically-accept-answers-to-old-questions). I don't think what I am suggesting is the same thing (mostly for the following reason)
- I am suggesting a feature to get fairer exposure to unanswered questions, not to force selecting an answer
- I am not suggesting this is a moderator responsibility, I don't think the issue is worthy of their time
- I am not suggesting automatic bounties (which would cause 'inflation')
- The reason I consider this important is that the unanswered list is something like 60k pages long. Without marking the oldest ones as answered, the ones anywhere near the middle of the queue will receive almost no attention, but might be answerable
- Yes people could just go through the list and upvote and hope it gets the question removed from 'unanswered', but most people wont, and many people (myself included) don't know what/if there is a criteria for getting questions of of that list without the OP selecting an answer. But people will use a visible feature like a review queue.

Comment: There already is such a review queue, it never empties.  You should perhaps focus on how adding another does not make that problem worse.

Comment: Which queue do you think is doing this? I see only queues for flags (close, low quality, reopen) and queues related to edits and quality (suggested edits, triage, first posts, help & improvement, late answers). None of them seem related to this

Comment: The Close Votes queue is intended to draw attention to questions that should be closed and possibly removed.  Fwiw, it would be very nice if the OP posts an "there is no good way to do this" answer and accepts it.  But they never do, the reader has to infer it from what is there.

Comment: The close queue requires someone to flag it first (as far as I am aware), but in any case isn't what I am suggesting. I am not looking to close these questions. I'm looking to cleanup the unanswered list so that it's not always the same few questions being viewed

Comment: Well, do keep in mind that this is an enormous amount of effort to solve a rather small problem.  Maybe you can think of a better way to organize that list, the age of the post certainly ought to play a role.  Nobody *really* wants to see dead old questions on this list.  Admittedly I never use it, there are 12000+ new ones every day, so no real idea what it takes to make it more usable.

Comment: So you are proposing a queue where we have to vote, with the culmination being...notifying the user who asked the question to accept an answer? Kind of anti-climactic. What is the point in having a queue? We could just use a set of criteria to notify users who have positively-scored answers to their old questions to accept one of those answers.

Comment: Well, the reasoning was to get attention for those questions so they actually get upvotes in the first place and can be removed from 'unanswered', instead of having 60,000 pages of unanswered where only the very newest and very oldest get any views. I wasn't aiming for a huge climax, just something to make unanswered more useful

Comment: I don't want more review queues. Not until the robo-reviewer problem is dealt with. As an alternative, how about [this request to give a badge for answering Tumbleweed questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271915/can-we-add-a-badge-having-similar-criteria-as-weed-eater-hat)?

Comment: @S.L.Barth that might work, but personally besides aiming for a Gold tag badge I don't have much interest in them. I don't know if mine is a common view. Even with that solution it still leaves the issue of people needing to be able to find these tumbleweed questions, somewhere in the middle of that huge list

Comment: @NickCardoso The biggest risk with a badge is that it may encourge people too much, especially if it's gold. Finding Tumbleweed questions is easy enough: http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/63/tumbleweed .

Comment: I think it's ironic that I found a post that belongs on such a queue as you propose when I was looking for exactly the same thing...

Comment: The solution to this issue is to automate it. Questions that remain open for too long get closed. No need to flag them, review them, chew them, mediate over their existential existence, just delete them.

Comment: You should also perhaps start to rank questions like google, if you don't already do so. Questions that "never" get recalled need to be deleted ultimately too. The bigger the db behind SO gets, the harder it is going to get to sort the wood from the trees.